# Building configuration files with Amazon Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm building an Amazon CloudFormation script which requires me to configure a reverse proxy with a few values filled in. I've seen people doing this sort of thing:

```
"Fn::Join": [
  "",
  [
    "events {\n",
    "  worker_connections 1024;\n",
    "}\n",
    "http {\n",
    "  server {\n",
    "    location / {\n",
    "      proxy_pass http://",
    {
      "Fn::GetAtt": [
        "FELoadBalancer",
        "DNSName"
      ]
    },
    ";\n",
    "      proxy_read_timeout 90;\n",
    "      proxy_redirect default;\n",
    "      proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;\n",
    "      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;\n",
    "      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;\n",
    "    }\n",
    "  }\n",
    "}\n"
  ]
]
```

But this is, well, god-awful-ugly.

Is there a more human readable and more easily maintainable way for me to build these configuration sections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already suggested, use YAML instead, https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-cloudformation-update-yaml-cross-stack-references-simplified-substitution/, something like:

```
UserData:
  'Fn::Base64': !Sub
    - |
      events {
        worker_connections 1024;
      }
      http {
        server {
          location / {
            proxy_pass http://"
              Fn::GetAtt:
                FELoadBalancer
                DNSName
              ;
            proxy_read_timeout 90;
            proxy_redirect default;
            proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          }
        }
      }
```

Beyond that you might be able to use a cloud boothook which can be defined in a file on the instance? http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/format.html#cloud-boothook

Comment: I'm going to give you this one because you provided a bit more than just a link, good answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The only formats CloudFormation supports are JSON and YAML.

See [the CloudFormation docs](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/09/aws-cloudformation-introduces-yaml-template-support-and-cross-stack-references/) for more information about YAML.

You can also use third-party frameworks that allow you to code your infrastructure in different formats, and let them distill them into JSON/YAML for you.  See [this example](https://www.terraform.io/) for a popular framework.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at mustache template.  I haven't used them but it seems like this is what they are for.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html#aws-resource-init-files